# What happens when you remove the Angular root element

Tags: angular

I'm manually bootstrapping an Angular application.

```
ngDoBootstrap(app) {
    app.bootstrap(AppComponent);
}
```

When the root element is removed from the DOM I wait for it to be injected again and manually bootstrap the application another time. This happens many, many times. (I'm using Angular within a larger app...).

So far it works well but I'm concerned that simply removing the element isn't going to clean things up. Is there anything else I should do to 'unbootstrap' the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best you can do is check the bootstrap method implementation in the Angular source code.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/44dd764d6d6582d92d3709501258cdb51c3ea85d/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts#L453

Here are the main points of interest (part of the code is omitted for clarity):

```js
bootstrap<C>(componentOrFactory: ComponentFactory<C>|Type<C>, rootSelectorOrNode?: string|any): ComponentRef<C> {
    const compRef = componentFactory.create(Injector.NULL, [], selectorOrNode, ngModule);

    compRef.onDestroy(() => { this._unloadComponent(compRef); });

    this._loadComponent(compRef);

    return compRef;
}
```

You can see that each time on bootstrap a component with a new injector is created. On destroy `this._unloadComponent` destroys the associated view and component instances. If you're unsure if `onDestroy` is triggered on element's removal, you can trigger it yourself on the component ref that is returned by a bootstrap method:

```
const compRef: ComponentRef<AppComponent> = app.bootstrap(AppComponent);
// some time later
compRef.destroy();
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I've saved link to compRef into global window, then have to navigate and insert DOM by jQuery navigation which was implemented long time before me. So for now I can manage destroying! :)

Comment: @Cyclion glad It helped :)

Comment: @Cyclion, I tried the same saving compref in window like window['active-angular'] and calling window['active-angular'].destroy(); when I want to destroy. But I am getting this error.  The selector "app2-root" did not match any elements when trying to load the other app. Please help

Comment: @CharanbabuKarnam looks like this deserves a separate question instead of a comment (with the minimal reproducible example).